# JS Passing a function that is part of a global object instance completely ignores the instance itself

Tags: javascript, object, parameter-passing

I have an object for a binary search tree that has the following functions

```
function BSTAVL() {
    /*
    Other functions not related to the question
    */
    this.inorder = function(cur = this.root) {
        var numbers = [];
        if (cur != null) {
            numbers = this.inorder(cur.left);
            numbers.push(cur.value);
            numbers = numbers.concat(this.inorder(cur.right));
        }
        return numbers;
    }

    this.preorder = function(cur = this.root) {
        var numbers = [];
        if (cur != null) {
            numbers = [cur.value];
            numbers = numbers.concat(this.preorder(cur.left));
            numbers = numbers.concat(this.preorder(cur.right));
        }
        return numbers;
    }

    this.postorder = function(cur = this.root) {
        var numbers = [];
        if (cur != null) {
            numbers = numbers.concat(this.postorder(cur.left));
            numbers = numbers.concat(this.postorder(cur.right));
            numbers = [cur.value];
        }
        return numbers;
    }
}

var bst = new BSTAVL();
```

`this.root` is a node object that represents the root of the tree.

and in the html file I have the following buttons

```
<button type="button" onclick="Print(bst.inorder);">Inorder</button>
<button type="button" onclick="Print(bst.preorder);">Preorder</button>
<button type="button" onclick="Print(bst.postorder);">Postorder</button>
<br>
<span id="msg"></span>
```

This function works as expected.

```
function PrintInorder() {
    var numbers = bst.inorder();
    msg.innerHTML = numbers.join(', ')
}
```

Now this is where the problem occurs, this `Print` function returns an empty array, when I traced it `this.root` inside the function was null, while in the instance `bst` it is not.

```
function Print(traversal) {
    var numbers = traversal();
    msg.innerHTML = numbers.join(', ');
}
```

What I want is to have just one `Print` function that takes a function, executes it and then prints the resulting numbers to the page instead of writing three separate identical functions `PrintInorder`, `PrintPreorder` and `PrintPostorder`

I don't understand why does that happen. I am passing `bst.inorder` so the passed function must have the root (`this.root`) of the instance `bst`, but instead it is just null.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define your function in order to accept a function as first parameter and the context of the called function as second parameter:

```
function Print(myFn, context) {
    myFn.call(context, context.root);
}
```

Then invocating the function you can pass the corresponding parameters:

```
<button type="button" onclick="Print(bst.inorder, bst);">Inorder</button>
```

Comment: `Print(bst.inorder.bind(bst))` is enough.